# componentDidUpdate does not get called when fetching object

Tags: reactjs

componentDidUpdate does not get fired, when the state changes.

Pretty much what the user interface is,

A user enters a image title value, and uploads the image. And componentDidUpdate should fetch the update values

and map it accordingly like this

```
this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
    <Grid item sm={12} md={12} key={i} style={{ margin: '30px 0px'}}>
            <Paper>
                <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.image_title}</Typography>
            <Image image_url={img.img_url} />    
        </Paper>                              
    </Grid>
))
```

However componentDidUpdate is not even fetching the console.logs in the componentDidUpdate method.

So what happens is that **Only on refresh am i able to see the updated values and it mapped accordingly.**

How would i be able to properly update the state without refresh, allowing me to see the appended values being passed in the array of `images` ?

**react**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import Image from './Image';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            image_url: 'http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg', 
            images: {}, 
            description:'',
            upload:false,
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        console.log(this.state.description)
        // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                image_url:response.data.img_url,
                description:response.data.image_title
                // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
            })
        });
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
        console.log(this.state.image_url);
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
        // console.log(this.state.description)
    }
    fileOnchange = (file) => {
        this.setState({
            [file[0].target.name]: file[0].target.value
        })
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
            // let img;
            // let imgTitle;
            // Object.keys(response.data).forEach( (key) => {
            //     img = response.data[key].img_url
            //     imgTitle = response.data[key].image_title
            //     console.log(response.data);
            //     // console.log(key, img);


            //     console.log(this.state.images);
            // });

            this.setState({
                images: response.data
            })
        })


    }
    componentDidUpdate(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.image_url !== prevState.image_url) {
                console.log(nextProps.images); // doesnt fetch console log
                console.log(prevState.images); // doesnt fetch console log
                this.setState({
                    images: [ this.state.image_url, this.state.description, this.state.images]
                });
        }

        // console.log(this.state.images); 
    }
    onUploadClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            upload: !this.state.upload
        })
    }
    render(){
        const uploader = ( 
            <ImageUploader
                withIcon={true}
                withPreview={true}
                onChange={this.handleUpload}
                singleImage={true}
                buttonText='Upload an image'
                imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                maxFileSize={5242880}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} md={6} style={{ margin: '40px 0px', padding: '0px 30px'}}>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Welcome to the Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                        <Button onClick={this.onUploadClick} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                            {/* toggle between Upload or Close
                                Will be upload by default, else if upload is clicked, close will show.
                            */}
                            {!this.state.upload ? "Upload": "Close"}
                        </Button>
                        {this.state.upload ? (
                            <div>
                             <TextField
                                 id="outlined-name"
                                 label="Image Title"
                                 name="description"
                                 type="text"
                                 fullWidth
                                 style={{ borderRadius: '0px'}}
                                 className=""
                                 value={this.state.description}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 margin="normal"
                               />
                                <br></br>
                                <br></br>
                              {uploader}
                            </div>
                        ):(
                            null
                        )}
                    {this.state.images.length > 0 ? (
                        this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
                            <Grid item sm={12} md={12} key={i} style={{ margin: '30px 0px'}}>
                                 <Paper>
                                     <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.image_title}</Typography>
                                    <Image image_url={img.img_url} />    
                                </Paper>                              
                            </Grid>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Grid item md={8}>
                                <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Grid>
                {/* Images  */}
              </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

console.log(response)

```
{
  "data": {
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559943872/uploads/iobe6hc1qkfqxnyww8ki.png",
    "image_title": "foo",
    "id": 66
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "135"
  },
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N***********sgNUmaIg"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "baseURL": "http://localhost:3000",
    "withCredentials": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/images/upload",
    "data": {}
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

Comment: replace `componentWillMount`  with  `componentDidMount`, componentWillMount is deprecated.

Comment: Not thats not what im looking for. ComponentWillMount is fetching the posts from the api quite fine. I need something will update the state when a file is uploaded. So componentDidupdate is the viable solution, i just need a better logic.

Comment: What does this.state.image_url  log in componentDidMount? Is it the new Image URL or still the old URL?

Comment: And I'm saying `componentWillMount` is deprecated, I'm not answering your question.

Comment: i think i got it working, ill post answer in a minute

Comment: please see https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1575

Comment: @JuniusL. thanks for the heads up. though.

Answer (score 1):

There are some critical issues that may lead to a very nasty bugs:

- on the init state you have `images: {}` (object), and later, in the `componentDidUpdate` function you're trying to set it as an array: `[ this.state.image_url, this.state.description, this.state.images]`. Don't do like this, it's very confusing.
- the condition `if (this.state.image_url !== prevState.image_url)` is going to fire only if your `Axios.post` promise resolves with success. Could you please share the result of the `console.log(response);`? Otherwise, it will never going to be triggered, at least based on this snippet

**Update**:
I've found the real cause, why you can't see the image (or you probably can see the broken ones):

1. The upload function should extend the existing array of images. I've slightly adapt the Axios.post function just to be able to compile it on my side, but you've got the point:

```
handleUpload =  file =>  {
    const data = new FormData()
    const image = file[0]
    console.log(this.state.description)
    // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
    data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )

    const axiosPost = new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => res({
        data: {
          image_url: "newURL",
          image_title: "newTitle",
          description: 'a description'
        }
      }), 2000);
    });

    axiosPost.then(response => {
      const { image_url, description } = response.data;
      this.setState({
        image_url,
        description,
        images: [...this.state.images, response.data ]
      })
    });
    // this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
    console.log(this.state.image_url);
  }
```

2. you're re-declaring the `images` var with the new array of 3 items on each `componentDidUpdate`, that completely doesn't make any sense. Could you please explain what you really trying to achieve in this life-cycle? Because everything that you need is happens in the `handleUpload` function (the state update)

Comment: ok thanks, will show you the console.log(response) in a few seconds.

Comment: and you said to not do it like that because its confusing, what will be another way of doing it ?

Comment: set as an empty array `images: []`, 'cause this check in the `render()` method may crash your app - `this.state.images.length > 0 ? (`

Comment: BTW, on the example image you have a typo in a word *sequelize*

Comment: next: don't forget to pass props into the constructors super function: `super(props);`